# MEF - No parameterless constructor defined for this object, et al

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

I am brand new to MEF and am stuck in "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" hell.  I've looked at a lot of posts etc. over the last many hours and am totally stuck.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm using .`NET 4.5`, so do I still need all these attributes? Am I mixing older style `MEF` in with newer?

UPDATE:

The solution I'm working on also references Unity 3.3, so I think they may be stepping on each other.  Do I need to remove Unity?

```
    [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHomeService _service;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public HomeController(IHomeService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IHomeService))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class HomeService : IHomeService
    {
        private readonly IServiceSearch _serviceSearch;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public HomeService(IServiceSearch serviceSearch)
        {
            _serviceSearch = serviceSearch;
        }
    }

    [InheritedExport]
    public interface IHomeService
    {
       // ...
    }

    [Export(typeof(IServiceSearch))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class ServiceSearch : DataHub.Search, IServiceSearch
    {

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public ServiceSearch(IMapper<xxx, xxxDTO> x)
        {
           // ...
        }

    [InheritedExport]
    public interface IMapper<TDomain,TDto>
    {
        TDomain ToDomain(object o);
        void Initialize();
        TDto DomainToDto(TDomain domain);
    }

 [Export(typeof(IMapper<Account, AccountDTO>))]
    public class AccountMapper : IMapper<Account, AccountDTO>
    {
     //....
    }

    protected void Application_OnStart()
    {            
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var composition = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        IControllerFactory mefControllerFactory = new MefControllerFactory(composition); //Get Factory to be used
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(mefControllerFactory);
    }

    public class MefControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly CompositionContainer _container;
        public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            Lazy<object, object> export = _container.GetExports(controllerType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();

            return null == export
                                ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
                                : (IController)export.Value;
        }
        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            ((IDisposable)controller).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've not encountered an error with MEF for `No parameterless constructor defined for this object`; rather, the error will state which object is missing the parameterless .ctor. What is the exact error? Which class is missing the parameterless .ctor?

Comment: Looking at the code provided, neither HomeController nor HomeService have parameterless constructors.

Comment: @MarkLarter...They're not suppose to.  If I add one, the dependencies aren't injected

Comment: @MetroSmurf...It's HomeController, if I add one, then no complaints, but the dependencies aren't injected either

Comment: You seem to be missing an implementation for `IServiceSearch`...

Comment: It looks like a bit of research is needed on how to instruct MEF to use the non-default constructor and supply the dependency you want to inject for this class, assuming MEF supports this sort of thing. You might have a look at this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941158/mef-constructor-parameters-with-multiple-constructors

Comment: Looking at the implied dependency chain:  HomeController(IHomeService) -> HomeService(IServiceSearch) -> ServiceSearch(IMapper) -> ????

No part listed seems to implement IMapper that could be used to create an instance of ServiceSearch.

Comment: @MonroeThomas...You're right I missed that.  I've edited my post to reflect the IMapper implementation.  I am still, unfortunately, still only hitting the default ctor, not the one with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get your code working with these modifications:

1. <s>Move the types nested inside `ServiceSearch` outside of it. I don't think that MEF supports nested types.</s> (Looks as though this is just a typo in the code sample above. I don't think it was intended.)
2. Remove the `InheritedExportAttribute` from `IMapper<,>`. You have an explicit export on `AccountMapper` anyway. Without making this change, you end up with `AccountMapper` being exported twice. The import into `ServiceSearch`'s constructor then fails because MEF doesn't know which of the two matching exports to use.  **Alternatively** keep the `InheritedExportAttribute` and remove the explicit export.
3. Either remove the `InheritedExportAttribute` on `IHomeService` or the `ExportAttribute` on `HomeService`, for the same reason as above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean for #1.  For 2 and 3, I thought that [Export] and  [InheritedImport] are both required.  Why is this wrong?

Comment: `InheritedExportAttribute` automatically applies an export to all derived types. `ExportAttribute` exports just the type on which it appears. When you have both, the type ends up being exported twice.

Comment: Regarding #1, this may just be a typo in your code, but the `ServiceSearch` class doesn't have a closing "}" so when I copied your code into a new project for testing, I thought the following types (`IMapper<,>`, etc.) were supposed to be inside it. I think you can ignore #1.