# Null interface in the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, mef

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using MEF to import my interfaces. The problem is that my `IVotesRepository` interface is null when it's passed to the constructor.

Here is the code from my controller:

```
public class VotesController : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /Votes/
    IVotesRepository VotesRepository;
    IAccountRepository accountRepository;

    public VotesController(IVotesRepository votesRepo, IAccountRepository accountRepo)
    {
        VotesRepository = votesRepo;
        accountRepository = accountRepo;
    }
```

And here is the interface and the repository itself:

```
public interface IVotesRepository
{
    void SaveVotes(int TeamId, int GameId, int UserId);

    bool CheckIfUserHaveVoted(int UserId, int GameId);
}

[Export(typeof(IVotesRepository))]
public class VotesRepository : IVotesRepository
{
   ...
}
```

Why is the `IVotesRepository` instance null?

EDIT:

Stack trace:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object at SocialSport.Controllers.VotesController.SaveVotes(Nullable`1 TeamId, Nullable`1 GameId) in C:\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SocialSport\Implementation\Source\SocialSportWeb\Controllers\VotesController.cs:line 29
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you need to do inline highlighting, use a pair of backticks (`). Otherwise, use the code formatting button (the pair of curly braces in the editor) for blocks of code, like your classes and interfaces.

Comment: I don't see the [`ImportingConstructorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importingconstructorattribute.aspx) on the constructor.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2008133/50776) on how to do it correctly.

Comment: @casperOne I've already tried the `[ImportConstructor]` attribute and still doesn't work, the funny thing is that it was working before, and in my other controllers I have the same code but with other interfaces and they work, this one is the only one that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that somewhere in my app I've unregistered that interface somehow, so I've made another interface and now it's working, sorry if it's a dirty fix, but I didn't had the time to make the proper corrections, thanks for your help.